# TypeError: 'function' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to add more to my code so that you are only allowed to enter specific parameters. Ever since I did that I can no longer get the code to run completely without it telling me it cannot be interpreted as an integer. I'm new to Python and would like to work it out.Tried converting range(length) to an int and str but i'm assuming i'm going about it the wrong way. Any tips appreciated.

```
import random
import string

def char_length():
    while True:
        char_length = input("How many characters would you like your password to be? ")
        if char_length.isdigit() and 0 < int(char_length) < 51:
            char_length = int(char_length)
            return
        else:
            print('Response must be a number between 0 and 50')
char_length()

def random_pass(length):
   while True:
      spec_char = input("Would you like special characters in your password? ")
      if spec_char == "Yes":
          characters =  string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
          password = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for i in range(length))
          print("Your password is: ", password)
          return
      elif spec_char == "No":
          characters = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(length))
          print("Your password is: ", characters)
          return
      else:
          print("Please only type Yes or No")

random_pass(char_length)
```

Comment: You're confusing yourself by using the same name for a variable and function.

Comment: The function should return a value. You can assign that to another variable, then use that as the argument to `random_pass()`.

Comment: There are several problems in this code.  The first is that you are using the same name for a function and a variable.  While not necessarily a bug, it certainly makes the code more confusing.  The second is that the function `char_length` doesn't return anything.  So it inputs a variable called `char_length`, checks it, then discards it and returns.  Later, when you call `random_pass`, you pass it `char_length`, which is the function, not the variable with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions should return the values they've generated, rather than just doing a bare `return` (which implicitly returns `None`).  You can then get that value by actually calling the function with `()`.  See the comments in the fixed code:

```
import random
import string

def char_length():
    while True:
        # don't reuse the function name for your local length variable
        length = input("How many characters would you like your password to be? ")
        if length.isdigit() and 0 < int(length) < 51:
            return int(length)  # need to actually return the converted length
        else:
            print('Response must be a number between 0 and 50')

def random_pass(length):
    while True:
        spec_char = input("Would you like special characters in your password? ")
        if spec_char == "Yes":
            characters =  string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
            password = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for i in range(length))
            print("Your password is: ", password)
            return password  # return the password
        elif spec_char == "No":
            characters = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(length))
            print("Your password is: ", characters)
            return characters  # again, return the password (but here it's the "characters" var)
        else:
            print("Please only type Yes or No")

random_pass(char_length())  # call char_length and pass the result to random_pass
```

The error in your original code was because you were passing `char_length` (the function) as the argument to `random_pass`, rather than `char_length()` (the result of *calling* the function, which will be an `int`).